# Access all environment variables from native iOS C code

Tags: c++, ios, c, environment-variables

I have to port an existing code written in C and C++ to iOS.

This code, at some point, uses the [`environ`](http://linux.die.net/man/5/environ) variable to access all the environment variables.

When compiling this code with the iOS compiler toolchain, it complains that `environ` is not a defined symbol. I couldn't find any header that would provide it or any suitable alternative.

Unfortunately, `environ` is used to get **all** the environment variables and pass them to a sub-routine. That is, `getenv()` is not an option, since we don't know what environment variables to check for.

Is there a way in C or C++ code, with the iOS compiler toolchain, to access to the `environ` variable ? Or do you know any alternative solution ?

Comment: I don't know iOS, but does it perhaps support the "extended" `main` signature `int main(int argc, char **argv, char **envp)`?

Comment: What environment variables do you need to access? You might find this kind of access very restricted due to sandboxing.

Comment: @Angew: Unfortunately, I have to compile this code as a static library, so there is no such entry point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `environ` variable must be declared in the user program, in your C code. So just declare it like this before accessing:

```
extern char **environ;
```

You may also find [this article](http://chaosinmotion.com/blog/?p=829) about iOS environment helpful (it has an example project as well).

Comment: Amazingly simple. Thanks a lot, wasn't aware a simple `extern` declaration would work.